# How to write data to specific sheet based on value selected from combobox?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a userform in Visual Basic and I am looking for a way to send a whole row of data from multiple inputs to a specific sheet based on the value selected in a combobox.

I am using this to calculate delivery driver efficiency based on different routes that their own formulas. There are 2 comboboxes one is the route # and the other is the driver name. I have a sheet for each route as well as a sheet for each driver. I would like to send the data to the route # sheet and also send it to the driver name sheet.

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What does "send data to specific sheet" mean? Do you mean "writing to a sheet specified by its name"? What does "send a whole row of data" mean? Do you mean "write a row of data"? A two-minute search here on `[excel-vba] select sheet by name` turned up a post that contained a link to [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291308), which seems to have a lot of useful suggestions on selecting a range of cells in various ways.

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't know how to word this well but how can i write data to a sheet based on the selection of a combobox. I want to write the same data to 2 sheets again based on the selection of each combobox. Thanks for the link it is very helpful if you could point me in the right direction of any info on my question (if you understand what I'm asking) I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The essential code is:

```
If Me.ComboBoxName.Value = "Whatever" Then
    Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A1").Value = Me.SomeTextBoxName.Text
End If
```

If you are using a number of individual textboxes then you need to insert the text individually, for each textbox.

Otherwise, you'll need to clarify what you mean by *inputs* and a *row of data* (of the form).

Comment: I have a userform with 2 comboxes one contains the numbers 1-25 (for the route), the other is each drivers name. I also have textboxes for other data times, mileage, cases, pallets, etc. I want to write the data to 2 different sheets based on the value of each combobox. I have individual sheets for each route as well as each driver. I have never used visual basic before so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have provided some essential code in my answer. If you cannot make use of it then you'll need to study the fundamentals of VBA. Ken has provided a good link about Range.

Comment: Perhaps `Worksheets(Me.ComboBoxName.Value).Range ...` is what is needed?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways you can implement a combo box:

1. From the Control toolbox. Right-click -> properties will let you
   choose LinkedCell, which is the selected value of the drop down box
   replicated into an Excel cell.
2. From the Forms toolbox. Right-click -> Format Control -> Control (tab) will let you pick the Cell Link.
3. Use Data Validation -> Settings -> Validation Criteria -> Allow -> List. This utilize the cell itself and turns it into a combo box.

Option 3 is my preferred approach.

No, you don't need Macro/VBA.